# Update values in XML file 

Tags: python, xml, perl

I am having XML file with the following format:

```
<Principal ID="122" >
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/>
</Principal>
<Principal ID="123" >
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/>
</Principal>
<Principal ID="124" >
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/>
</Principal>
<Principal ID="125" >
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/>
</Principal>
```

I need to update `${Fees}` variable with Fees1, Fees2, Fees3 and so on. There are more than 365 records.
Can someone help me how to do this through Perl or Python?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The data as you show it is not well-formed XML, it is a series of XML fragments, but it is missing a root element. That makes it difficult to test code, and decrease the likelihood of you getting help. The structure of the update data is also unclear: is it several variables (which would be ugly), an array, with the same order as the `Status` elements, or a hash maybe with IDs as keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good idea to use regex for xml manipulation, but in this case I would use it anyway:

***Perl Script:***

```
my $xml = join (/\n/, <main::DATA>);
my @fees = (1, 2, 3, 4);

$xml =~ s/(<Status Fees=")\${Fees}("\/>)/{$1 . shift(@fees) . $2}/ige;

print "$xml";

__DATA__
<Principal ID="122" > 
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="123" > 
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="124" > 
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="125" > 
<Status Fees="${Fees}"/> 
</Principal>
```

***Output:***

```
<Principal ID="122" > 
<Status Fees="1"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="123" > 
<Status Fees="2"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="124" > 
<Status Fees="3"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="125" > 
<Status Fees="4"/> 
</Principal>
```

See and test it [here](http://ideone.com/WPJsd).

---

In case you want to replace `${Fees}` with the actual value of `$Fees` variable and the name of this variable change, then go with:

***Perl Script:***

```
my $xml = join (/\n/, <main::DATA>);
my ($fee1, $fee2, $fee3, $fee4) = (1, 2, 3, 4);

$xml =~ s/(<Status Fees=")\${(.*?)}("\/>)/{$1 . eval('$'.$2) . $3}/ige;

print "$xml";

__DATA__
<Principal ID="122" > 
<Status Fees="${fee1}"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="123" > 
<Status Fees="${fee2}"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="124" > 
<Status Fees="${fee3}"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="125" > 
<Status Fees="${fee4}"/> 
</Principal>
```

***Output:***

```
<Principal ID="122" > 
<Status Fees="1"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="123" > 
<Status Fees="2"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="124" > 
<Status Fees="3"/> 
</Principal> 
<Principal ID="125" > 
<Status Fees="4"/> 
</Principal>
```

See and test it [here](http://ideone.com/1WtKS).

Answer (score 0):

Short Python version.  Quite inefficient, but runs instantlish over 365 entries.

```
xml = open("INPUT.XML","rb").read()
count = 1
while "${Fees}" in xml:
    xml = xml.replace("${Fees}", "Fees%d"%count, 1)
    count += 1
open("OUTPUT.XML","wb").write(xml)
```